# PHPTumblr REALLY Slow?

Tags: php, optimization, tumblr

I am trying to use PHPTumblr to pull posts from my Tumblr blog onto my PHP website. All I want to happen is for the home page of my website to display the latest title and a preview of the content.

This is the code I am using:

```
$tumblr = new readTumblr('<blogname>'); 
$tumblr->getPosts(0,1);
$posts = $tumblr->dumpArray();
$post = reset($posts['posts']);

$title = $post['content']['title'];
$content = $post['content']['body'];
```

The trouble is, when I add this to the page it adds about 5-10 seconds of load time! Without the code it loads instantly! I assume this is because it is pulling from a remote server but a load time increase of that can't be normal, surely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems reasonable to load a remote page. If you don't want the delay, try periodically loading it in the background with cron.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's a good idea though thanks i will do that.